# C values being remove from linked list after adding them

Tags: c

I would like to understand how come in my linked list are elements in it but they are all empty strings after adding strings to it.  It seems like there is some issue when I set the terminating string character but I believe I am making a copy of it and adding the copy to the linked list.  This is the code I have.

```
        char name[256] = " ";
        while (serial.available()) {
            char text= serial.read();
            Print(text);
            if (text== '\n') {
              char copy[256];
              strcpy(copy, name);
               add(copy, list); //adds copy to a linkedlist named list
               name[0] = '\0';
            } else {
                append(name, text);
            }
        }
```

After function call, the linked list has a bunch of elements in it but they are all empty strings.  Any idea of what the problem can be?

Comment: Perhaps showing some code that actually compiles? First you make `char text`, and then use `txt` directly after. Is this intentional? Also, you're allocating `copy` on the stack, which won't exist outside of that `if` block.

Comment: Although rather C-ish, your code is C++.  These are different languages.  Tags edited.

Comment: @yetanotherposter, C does not have member functions, and the period (`.`) is not a valid character in function names.  I don't care what the code is *for*.  It is not valid C.

Comment: Yeah I see your point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: It's possible, although admittedly pretty unlikely, that `serial` is a `struct`, and `read` and `available` are function pointer members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this declaration:

```
char copy[256];
```

`copy` is a local variable, so storing it for later use is not allowed.

Replace it with

```
char *copy = new char[256];
```

to get this problem fixed.